# How to schedule tasks in a specific thread without using a looper and a handler?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Timer creates its own thread and `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` uses a pool. Is their a way to specify the thread where the task will be executed directly without having to marshal any code? And if this is a bad idea, please explain why (beside the thread being busy).

I have no problem with the looper-handler approach, I'm just curious.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "specify the thread where the task will be executed"?

Comment: @azurefrog 

 I just mean the callback function. Timer executes it on its own thread, while ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor picks a thread from a pool. I want to know if it's possible to choose the thread myself where the callback function will be executed. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` with one single thread using `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()`.

Optionally, you can pass a `ThreadFactory` as parameter if you want to have more control about this single thread. The thread factory's `newThread(Runnable)` method is called every time the executor wants to have a new `Thread` instance that should run the given `Runnable` (which is not identical to the `Runnable` you pass to the executor's `execute(...)`, `submit(...)` or `schedule(...)` methods).

Note that you are not able to reuse an existing thread, as there is no way to 'inject' code into an already running thread in general, as it is possible in [Qt](http://www.qt.io/developers/). There, every thread has its own event queue and timing facility, so you can freely decide which (already existing) thread should process your timed task (see [Timers in Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/timers.html)).

There is no such feature in Java out of the box.

Comment: Can I use ThreadFactory to select an existing thread (like the main thread)?

Comment: No you can't. You have to implement `ThreadFactory.newThread(Runnable r)`, which gets the `Runnable` to be run by the thread. There is no way to 'inject' a `Runnable` into an already running thread in general.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like [Timers in Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/timers.html). There, every thread has its own event queue and timing facility, so you can freely decide which (already existing) thread should process your timed task. There is no such feature in Java out of the box.

Comment: @isnotbad Thanks. It would be great if you update your answer with this comment so I can set it as the accepted answer.